# How to get source code of Android Library directly when using gradle as android build system

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How to get source code of Android Library directly when using gradle as android build system?In fact the sourcecode.jar and javadoc.jar should be on the center repository,but I can hardly find a easy way to get them in my Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to the "build.gradle" file

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea{
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

For more details on the plugin see:  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

Comment: But I found that only some library's source and javadoc can be download while many others not.Is there any other thing I should do?

Comment: No all library developers post their source code and javadoc.  Which library are you using?

Comment: In fact,I can find most libraries which are posted in jcenter  have their source and javadoc. And I also mean them. For example,ButterKnife etc.